# unix:///tmp/supervisor.sock no such file

Tags: unix, supervisord, unix-socket

Using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS to deploy my python app. Configured everything and the app is running manually. I want to automate it with supervisor, I have installed supervisor and configured it. But if I run:

Supervisor config file:

```
; supervisor config file

[unix_http_server]
file=/var/run/supervisor.sock   ; (the path to the socket file)
chmod=0700                       ; sockef file mode (default 0700)

[supervisord]
logfile=/var/log/supervisor/supervisord.log ; (main log file;default $CWD/supervisord.log)
pidfile=/var/run/supervisord.pid ; (supervisord pidfile;default supervisord.pid)
childlogdir=/var/log/supervisor            ; ('AUTO' child log dir, default $TEMP)

; the below section must remain in the config file for RPC
; (supervisorctl/web interface) to work, additional interfaces may be
; added by defining them in separate rpcinterface: sections
[rpcinterface:supervisor]
supervisor.rpcinterface_factory = supervisor.rpcinterface:make_main_rpcinterface

[supervisorctl]
serverurl=unix:///var/run/supervisor.sock ; use a unix:// URL  for a unix socket

; The [include] section can just contain the "files" setting.  This
; setting can list multiple files (separated by whitespace or
; newlines).  It can also contain wildcards.  The filenames are
; interpreted as relative to this file.  Included files *cannot*
; include files themselves.

[include]
files = /etc/supervisor/conf.d/*.conf
```

`supervisorctl reread` I end up with `unix:///tmp/supervisor.sock no such file`

But `supervisord` status is running,

Anyone having an idea, please.

Comment: Try restarting the supervisord service. And also post output of `echo_supervisord_conf`.

Comment: This Q  **may** be more appropriate on the S.E. related site http://unix.stackexchange.com (Unix & Linux). Use the `flag` link at the bottom of your Q and ask the moderator to move it. Please don't post the same Q on 2 different sites. ***Please*** read  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask and http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve before posting more Qs here. Good luck.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Finally solved it by reinstalling `supervisor` after deleting all configuration files in `/etc/supervisor/conf.d/` this did the trick.

Comment: I followed this: 
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-manage-supervisor-on-ubuntu-and-debian-vps

Comment: config files surely can make those problems!

Answer (score 36):

Running this command `sudo service supervisord restart` solved my issue.

Some answers suggest re-installation, which is essentially doing this

Comment: i get "service not found" and removing the `d` brings no error, but it still doesn't work! 

Answer (score 10):

I had the same problem. After reading the `man supervisorctl` manual I realized the default file is `/etc/supervisord.conf` which in ubuntu is at `/etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf`. I created a symlink using:

```
sudo ln -s  /etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf /etc/supervisord.conf
```

This fixed my problem.

Comment: edit: I am refering to the default config file.

Comment: Guys, pay attention while copy-pasting. While I installed supervisor through pip on centos my supervisor config file is at /etc/supervisord/supervisord.conf

Comment: On Fedora my conf file had to have `.ini` extension. E.g. `/etc/supervisord.d/*.ini`

Answer (score 5):

Reason of getting this: There is multiple reasons, what I found is that my supervisor was got corrupted due to the server going down continuously by power tripping.

solution: Remove the supervisor first and then reinstall it.

Steps:

```
sudo apt-get remove supervisor

sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove supervisor

sudo apt-get purge supervisor

sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove supervisor
```

Link for the above can be found here :

https://www.howtoinstall.co/en/ubuntu/trusty/supervisor?action=remove

Answer (score 3):

The Ubuntu supervisor package (3.3.1-1.1) has the configuration file in `/etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf`.

For some reason (I don't know why) there appears to be another configuration file in `/etc/supervisord.conf` and supervisorctl prefers that file.

You can either define the configuration file location explicitly to supervisorctl:

```
sudo supervisorctl -c /etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf reread
```

or just remove `/etc/supervisord.conf`.

Comment: this is exactly what I am looking for. Saves my life.

Comment: After doing that it's better to execute Supervisord command to create a supervisor.sock

Answer (score 3):

Probably one of the configuration files has syntax errors.

For instance, verify if [program] clause is missing

Remove each file on conf.d directory and restart supervisor to isolate the problematic file.

Comment: This is right solution if there are no set up issues. This mostly shown up `supervisorctl` have not even initialised, copied wrong syntax error file. You can check `syslog` for more details.