# Supervisor socket error: Unlinking stale socket /tmp/supervisor.sock

Tags: laravel, sockets, shared-hosting, supervisord, unlink

I installed **Supervisor** on a shared Debian server. When I run:
`supervisord -c supervisord.conf`
I get this error continuously untill I kill it:`Unlinking stale socket /tmp/supervisor.sock`
When I run `supervisorctl status` I get: 
`unix:///tmp/supervisor.sock no such file`
My supervisord.conf file like this (I didn`t change anything):

```
[unix_http_server]
file=/tmp/supervisor.sock     ; (the path to the socket file)
;chmod=0700                 ; socket file mode (default 0700)

[supervisord]
logfile=/tmp/supervisord.log ; (main log file;default $CWD/supervisord.log)
logfile_maxbytes=50MB        ; (max main logfile bytes b4 rotation;default 50MB)
logfile_backups=10           ; (num of main logfile rotation backups;default 10)
loglevel=info                ; (log level;default info; others: debug,warn,trace)
pidfile=/tmp/supervisord.pid ; (supervisord pidfile;default supervisord.pid)
nodaemon=false               ; (start in foreground if true;default false)
minfds=1024                  ; (min. avail startup file descriptors;default 1024)
minprocs=200                 ; (min. avail process descriptors;default 200)

[rpcinterface:supervisor]
supervisor.rpcinterface_factory = supervisor.rpcinterface:make_main_rpcinterface

[supervisorctl]
serverurl=unix:///tmp/supervisor.sock   ; use a unix:// URL  for a unix socket

[program:laravel-worker]
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
command=php /path/to/app/artisan queue:work  --sleep=3 --tries=3
autostart=true
autorestart=true
;user=
numprocs=8
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile= /path/to/app/worker.log
```

When I cd to /tmp to look for the socket file, the socket looks like this:
**supervisor.sock.824804**. 
The six-digit number gets somehow generated randomly by the server after I run the `supervisord -c supervisord.conf`command. Do I have to consider this six-digit in the **supervisord.config** file? And how to I do this, since it gets generated randomly? I have already installed and run **Supervisor** on a **macOS Mojave** too and there were no problemes and the socket file just locked like supervisor.sock. Thank for any help and suggestion in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [unix:///tmp/supervisor.sock no such file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45957187/unix-tmp-supervisor-sock-no-such-file)

Comment: I know this post already. Tried some stuff, but to no avial. First, I have no admin right, so half of the suggestions doesn`t work for me. Secondly, my foremost problem is that after running supervisord -c supervisord.conf I am getting permanently **Unlinking stale socket /tmp/supervisor.sock**, while in that post supervisord is already running. I think it´s got something todo with six-digit number that my shared host is generating (supervisor.sock.824804 )randomly.

Answer (score 6):

I set `nodaemon = true` in `supervisord.conf` and that fixed my problem.

Answer (score 4):

`unlink /tmp/supervisor.sock`

then I fixed it "Unlinking stale socket /tmp/supervisord.sock".

Answer (score 0):

It's not a problem. Just inform you that supervisor is updating its socket file.

Answer (score 0):

I received a similar error and ended up having to change a file path in the directory

```
/lib/systemd/system/supervisor.service
```

Underneath [service], you should see:

```
ExecStart=/usr/bin/supervisord ......
ExecStop=/usr/bin/supervisorctl ......
ExecReload=/usr/bin/supervisorctl .......
```

I changed all these file paths to /usr/local/bin/supervisord, etc. I guess the reason for this is that when you use pip install, it places the config files in /usr/local/bin instead of the default which is /usr/bin.

Hopefully this helps!